# dateTimeType : I want to stop automatic conversion : Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to stop automatic conversion of a day that does not exist.

**FormType**

```
$builder
    ->add("start", new DateTimeType(), [
        "date_widget" => "single_text",
        "minutes" => [0, 20, 40],
        "required" => true,
    ])
;
```

**Validation**

```
//...
start:
    - DateTime: ~
    - NotBlank: ~
```

In this case, it will worked automatic conversion of value.
"2017-03-33" value was converted to "2017-04-02" value.
And it passed the form validation check.

I want to make an error if input value of form(the date) does not exist.

Thank you if you know.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is caused by the DateTimeType class. It uses DateTime::createFromFormat method for entered value conversion which auto-corrects the value to valid value.

More can be founded in this article https://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html

If the converted value was valid or invalid can be figured out by the DateTime::getLastErrors() method, so the solution for your desired behaviour is to custom DateTimeType class.

Quick untested example:

```
class CustomDateTimeType extends Type
{
    ...
    ...
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null || $value instanceof \DateTime) {
            return $value;
        }

        $val = \DateTime::createFromFormat($platform->getDateTimeFormatString(), $value);
        if( \DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count'] > 0 ) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailedFormat($value, $this->getName(), $platform->getDateTimeFormatString());
        }

        ...
        ...
```